# How to install pip on wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine, python, winetricks, pip

I fail to install `pip` by:

```
# install wine and python
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
winetricks python

# try to install pip
winetricks pip
```

BTW, there is no `pip.exe` under `Python26/Scripts`.

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Python26/Scripts$ ls
pywin32_postinstall.py  pywin32_postinstall.pyc  pywin32_postinstall.pyo
```

Comment: You could install newer Python versions that already include `pip`: `wine msiexec /i python-X.Y.Z.msi /L*v log.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer Python versions already include `pip`. Choose the proper version from [Download Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (for me, `python-2.7.10.msi`) and install it on wine by:

```
$ wine msiexec /i python-2.7.10.msi/L*v log.txt
```

To install Python packages on wine, for instance,

```
$ wine python.exe Scripts/pip.exe install pyinstaller

Successfully installed pyinstaller-3.1.1 pypiwin32-219
```

Refer to this post [Build a Windows executable from Python scripts on Linux](http://sparkandshine.net/build-a-windows-executable-from-python-scripts-on-linux/) for the detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer gets it right but for those who want to install Python 3 for Windows, pip is included and it can also be executed from the python binary.

wine python -m pip install pyinstaller

Follow this guide:
http://realtechtalk.com/How_To_Install_python_34_35_and_up_on_Linux_with_wine_Working_Solution-2288-articles